# laravel で breeze がインストールできない

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel

Windows 10 Pro 22H2 にDocker、Ubuntuを入れてlaravel をインストールできました。
しかし、brezze のインストールで躓いております。
`composer require laravel/breeze --dev`
上記コマンドの結果、下記のエラーが発生しました
`Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1`
エラーメッセージとして下記も出力されました

```
The /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable.

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php:178
    174▕      */
    175▕     protected function write(array $manifest)
    176▕     {
    177▕         if (! is_writable($dirname = dirname($this->manifestPath))) {
  ➜ 178▕             throw new Exception("The {$dirname} directory must be present and writable.");
    179▕         }
    180▕ 
    181▕         $this->files->replace(
    182▕             $this->manifestPath, '<?php return '.var_export($manifest, true).';'
```

察するにディレクトリがないか、書き込み権限がないのだと思いますが、どこのフォルダのことを指しているのかがわからないです。
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示願います。
・php 8.1.2
・Laravel Framework 10.13.5
・Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
・Client: Docker Engine - Community
Cloud integration: v1.0.33
Version:           24.0.2
・Server: Docker Desktop
Engine:
Version:          24.0.2
API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました
bootstrap 配下の cache ディレクトリに書き込み権限を設定したら解決いたしました。
ありがとうございました。